# Cancel multiple touches on the View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am adding UIPanGestureRecogniser to drag and drop images in a view.I want to drag only one image at a time.but I am able to drag two images at a time.which should not happen.

I am stuck with this bug since morning.I tried all the ways i found on google.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
[self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
for(UIImageView *iView in self.movableArray){
    if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        UIPanGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        [iView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [iView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
    }
}
}



 - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
     [gameView bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer view]];
     CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:gameView];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
     [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:gameView];
     self.dragObjectImageView =  (UIImageView*)recognizer.view;


if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
     int ind = [self.movableArray indexOfObject:self.dragObjectImageView];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < [self.movableArray count] ; i ++){
        if( i != ind ){
            [[self.movableArray objectAtIndex:i] removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        }

    }

    self.homePosition = self.dragObjectImageView.frame;
}
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:gameView];
    for (UIImageView *iView in self.staticArray) {
        if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            if (touchPoint.x > iView.frame.origin.x &&
                touchPoint.x < iView.frame.origin.x + iView.frame.size.width &&
                touchPoint.y > iView.frame.origin.y &&
                touchPoint.y < iView.frame.origin.y + iView.frame.size.height)
            {
                self.dropTargetImageView = iView;
            }
        }
    }

    if(self.dragObjectImageView.tag == self.dropTargetImageView.tag){
        self.dragObjectImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.dropTargetImageView.frame.origin.x, self.dropTargetImageView.frame.origin.y + self.dropTargetImageView.frame.size.height/2 - 15, self.dragObjectImageView.frame.size.width, self.dragObjectImageView.frame.size.height);
        [self.dragObjectImageView removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        }
    }else{
        self.dragObjectImageView.frame = self.homePosition;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are adding one `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for each of your `imageViews`. Try adding only one to your `self.view` (and have your `imageViews` to `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO`, otherwise they will trap the touch). Also put

```
recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
```

Before you add it to your view. All you have to do now is to test which image view should be dragged in your `handlePan` method. You should check the recognizer state and when it turns to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` you should save which `imageView` is being dragged. Then as the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` just drag the view around. The most general way you can find out which view was touched (as i don't know your full view hierarchy) would be to do something like:

```
NSUInteger index = [self.movableArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)){
    UIView* hitTest = (UIView*)obj;
    return [hitTest pointInside:firstTouch withEvent:nil];
}];
if ( index != NSNotFound )
   self.draggingView = self.moveableArray[index];
else
   self.draggingView = nil;
```

Then of course if self.draggingView is nil you would do nothing when the user is panning around.

Comment: Unexpected interface name UIView is the error i am getting while using this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a mechanism to `setUserInteractionEnable = NO` when your

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
```

Is called on the other images. You can either do that, or disable the others  `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, like: `myPanGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;`

A quick example:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  UIImageView *currentDraggedImageView = recognizer.view;
  // Based on this, you can iterate again on your UIImageViews and disable them.
  // Once your work is done with gesture recogniser, you can re-enable them.
}
```

Comment: Yes I changed the user interaction disabled to NO when I got the currentDraggedImageView like u suggested.Its working fine but if the user touches 2 images at a time those two are moving.